# Set Custom Toggle Hotkey for Grease Pencil Stroke Tools not Working?

Tags: shortcut, customization, grease-pencil

In Blender2.9, while trying to set a Custom Toggle Hotkey in User Preferences for GreasePencil-> Draw_on_Back command using `wm.context_toggle_enum` with context attribute `tool_settings.use_gpencil_draw_onback`, pressing the  hotkey(`END`) doesn't execute the toggle command .

Why isn't the toggle command getting activated by this hotkey?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The toggle hotkey has to be created in `Window context` rather than GreasePencil(Global).

[image]